# Why lsof command not found in shell script, but it works well in Terminal

Tags: shell

The lsof command in my shell script is not working, but it works well in Terminal. I have set the full path of the lsof command, but always throwout a error about this:

```
lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i :
lsof 4.89
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRtUvV] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[cgG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
 [+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.


function launchAnyproxy()
{
    cd ../..
    port=`/usr/sbin/lsof -t -i :8888`
    echo $port
    #port=`netstat -ln |grep '8888'`
    if [ ! -n "$port" ]; then
        anyproxy --intercept
    else
        echo "8888 is listening by other process"
    fi
}

launchAnyproxy
```

Comment: What was the exact command you ran in the shell?  Can you copy and paste your shell session to demonstrate that it works?  Can you simplify the shell script to the simplest thing that should work but doesn't and show how you run the shell script its full output?

Comment: It worked for me, with `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, making the script executable and calling it `./script`.  Using Linux Mint 18, GNU bash (version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)).  Same lsof (4.89) as you.  My lsof is in /usr/bin, not /usr/sbin like you.  Besides that, I took your code.  **FYI** you should use `port=$(.....)`, not backticks.  **FYI2** and I used sudo, for lsof to run ok.

Comment: May be you have two copies of lsof? in terminal, run `which lsof`, you will see what lsof works from command line.